# how to pass date time parameter as date in POSTMAN

Tags: postman

I'm trying to perform a GET where for a datetime field I shall pass only date and it should provide the necessary results. Below is the URL that I'm trying however it does not work

```
https://hostname/oslc/os/table?oslc.select=assetnum, location&oslc.where=assetstatus.code="ABC" and siteid="XXXX" and assetstatus.location="204345104" and assetstatus.changedate="2022-06-18"
```

The change date is stored in the database as `2022-06-18 08:00:01.0` however we would pass only date.

Comment: this is not a postman issue, you should handle the `date` in your backend, and save the correct data in your database

Comment: @AliRn The data will be datetime in the database however we would like to fetch the record by passing date only.

Answer (score 0):

Postman (or HTTP) does not have a concept of typed query parameters.

OSLC Query only requires support for the typed literals when it comes to datetimes. You read more about the OSLC Query format in https://docs.oasis-open-projects.org/oslc-op/query/v3.0/oslc-query.html

You can try to pass `"2022-06-18T00:00:00.0Z"^^xsd:dateTime` instead of `"2022-06-18"`.